# Returning the size of available virtual memory at run-time in C++

Tags: c++, windows

In C++ is there a predefined library function that will return the size of RAM currently available on a computer a program is being run on, at run-time?

For instance, if an object is 4bytes, then can we divide the available virtual memory by 4 bytes to give an *estimate* of how many more objects could be stored by the program safely?

I have used the sizeof() function to return the size of objects within my program.

Seeing as this was frequently asked for in the helpful responses - The platform the program is running on is Windows (7).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to virtual memory architectures, your computer will be curled up in a foetal position long before you use up all available memory. Virtual memory isn't a bad thing, of course; the idea is to give the illusion of having vastly more RAM than you really do, and to degrade gracefully as your program ramps up its memory consumption and sucks the life out of your OS. But don't be fooled into thinking that you can predict to the byte (or even the MB) how much memory you can safely consume.

Comment: I guess you could say the degradation is graceful from the *process's* point of view.  From the user's point of view, it's worrisome to see everything slow down like molasses and hear the hard drive thrash, but I guess it's better than a panic.

Comment: @Marcelo: Not true any more for 32-bit operating systems. For many applications, 2 GB of virtual address space is not a lot -- and it can be very useful to know how much is left.

Comment: @Martin, this is sort of true (virtual memory thrashing can still cause major hassles even on 4 GB machines), but of course this is a short-lived phenomenon while we transition to 64-bit systems.

Comment: @Marcelo: Short-lived... well, people are still installing 32-bit OSes on new machines today. It's going to take many years until those installations have trickled out of the installed base to the point that we don't have to support 32-bit any more. Until then, 32-bit is going to continue to be a pain.

Answer (score 6):

Not in the C++ Standard Library - your operating system probably provides this facility though, via a platform-specific API.

Comment: i am here because i am WRITING an operating system for ARM, now I feel scammed

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the C++ standard that returns the amount of free memory available.  Such a function, if available at all, would be platform-specific.

Answer (score 2):

First of all size of the RAM has nothing to do with how much free virtual memory available in the process. It just that your program will slow down if the RAM is less due to frequent page faults. Also, the virtual memory will be mostly fragmented so it makes more sense to find the things such as largest continuous free memory instead of total free memory.

There are no built in C++ functions to do this you have use OS API's to get it. For example, on windows you can use the Win32 APIs to get this information.

Answer (score 2):

It's platform specific, not part of the language standard.

However, there's a Windows specific API to get process memory informations: [GetProcessMemoryInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx).

Additionally, virtual addressing allow processes to allocate more than total physical RAM.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good solution for this in Windows.  When a program frees a heap block, it almost always gets added to a list of free blocks.  You can only discover these is by walking the heap with HeapWalk().  That's expensive and very detrimental to the operation of a multi-threaded program because you have to lock the heaps.

Also, a program almost never runs out of free virtual memory space.  It first runs out of a free contiguous chunk of space that's large enough to fit the request.  The sum of block sizes you get from HeapWalk is not meaningful unless you only ever make very small allocations.

The most typical reason for wanting a feature like this is because your program is routinely running out of memory.  There is a very effective and cheap solution available for that problem.  Two hundred bucks buys you a 64-bit version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 you can use

```
 MEMORYSTATUS st;
 ::GlobalMemoryStatus(&st);
```